# Recover the output from the previous Spyder Console

Tags: python, logging, console, spyder, data-recovery

So I accidentally clicked the x botton at the upper left corner of the Spyder console[image: x botton at the upper left corner of the Spyder console]

and consequently have lost some real time running data in the console output that will help me to debug. This piece of data cannot be replicated, so running the script again won't solve the problem and the only way to help the situation is to recover the lost console output

Note: Spyder version is 3.3.4

My question is:

1) Assume I haven't closed the Spyder yet, how to recover the previous console output?

2) If (1) is possible, is it possible to recover all the previous console outputs?

3) If I have actually closed the Spyder, Is it possible to recover the previous console output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) My answers:

> 1) Assume I haven't closed the Spyder yet, how to recover the previous console output?

No, all previous output in your console is lost.

> 3) If I have actually closed the Spyder, Is it possible to recover the previous console output?

No, because Spyder doesn't save the console output to disk.

---

*Note*: If you want to avoid this in the future, please go to the menu `Tools > Preferences > IPython console` and activate the option called `Ask confirmation before closing` so that Spyder asks you for confirmation before closing any console.

Comment: This is so sad.